# Black Magic in Haskell Reflection

Tags: haskell, reflection

I was hoping someone could shed a little light on the black magic in [Data.Reflection](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.3.2). The pertinent snippet is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module Data.Reflection
    (
      Reifies(..)
    , reify
    ) where

import Data.Proxy
import Unsafe.Coerce

class Reifies s a | s -> a where
  -- | Recover a value inside a 'reify' context, given a proxy for its
  -- reified type.
  reflect :: proxy s -> a

newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall (s :: *). Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r)

-- | Reify a value at the type level, to be recovered with 'reflect'.
reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall (s :: *). Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r
reify a k = unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a) Proxy
```

1. I can't parse the definition for `reify`. maybe I'm missing something simple about order of evaluation, but it looks like `unsafeCoerce::a->b` is applied to three arguments.
2. What are the isomorphic types used in the `unsafeCoerce`?
3. Where is the function `k` actually evaluated in the definition of `reify`?
4. Where are any instances for `Reifes`? For example, I can run the following line in GHCi only loading Data.Reflection and Data.Proxy (and setting -XScopedTypeVariables):.

   `reify (3::Int) (\(_:: Proxy q) -> print $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy q))`
5. Where/what is the phantom reified type?
6. What is the "magic" in `newtype Magic`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Before understanding this implementation, you should understand the API. The original idea (reflecting an arbitrary pointer to the type level) is explained in [this paper](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/prepose/prepose.pdf), which is implemented in the "[slow](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/blob/master/slow/Data/Reflection.hs)" version of `reflection`. So I'll assume you already know how that works, and how the API is used. "[fast](https://github.com/ekmett/reflection/blob/master/fast/Data/Reflection.hs)" is another implementation of the same API, which uses a somewhat GHC-specific trick to speed things up. So:

1. `unsafeCoerce :: a -> b` is indeed applied to three arguments, which means that `b` must be the type of a two-argument function. In particular, the type of this `unsafeCoerce` is something like: `Magic a r -> (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r`.
2. Heh. "isomorphic".

   More seriously: It's important to understand GHC's implementation of type classes, which involves dictionary passing. When you have something like

   ```
   class Num a where
     plus :: a -> a -> a
     negate :: a -> a
   foo :: Num a => a -> a
   foo x = plus x (negate x)
   ```

   It gets translated into something like

   ```
   data Num a = Num { plus :: a -> a -> a, negate :: a -> a }
   foo :: Num a -> a -> a
   foo dict x = plus dict x (negate dict x)
   ```

   With GHC figuring out which dictionary to pass in based on the type when you use `foo`. Note how a one-argument function turned into a two-argument function.

   So the implementation of a type class is to pass an extra dictionary argument. But note that as an optimization, we can use `newtype` instead of `data` when the class only has one method. E.g.

   ```
   class Default a where
     def :: a
   doubleDef :: Default a => (a, a)
   doubleDef = (def, def)
   ```

   turns into

   ```
   newtype Default a = Default { def :: a }
   doubleDef :: Default a -> (a, a)
   doubleDef dict = (def dict, def dict)
   ```

   But this generated `def` is operationally `unsafeCoerce`.
3. `Magic k` *is* `k`, just with a different type. So the function `unsafeCoerce (Magic k)` is the function `k`, with its type modified. It's all the same function.
4. So let's think about how this class gets compiled (I'm going to switch to `Proxy` with a capital `P` to simplify things).

   ```
   class Reifies s a | s -> a where
     reflect :: Proxy s -> a
   foo :: Reifies s a => ...
   ```

   turns into

   ```
   newtype Reifies s a = Reifies { reflect :: Proxy s -> a }
   foo :: Reifies s a -> ...
   -- which is unsafeCoerce-compatible with
   foo :: (Proxy s -> a) -> ...
   ```

   So, operationally,

   ```
   newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r)
   ```

   is `unsafeCoerce`-compatible with

   ```
   newtype Magic a r = Magic (forall s. (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r)
   ```
5. So now we can see how this works:

   `reify` gets two arguments, a value `:: a` and a function `:: forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r`. Since the function is conveniently the same shape as `Magic`, we turn it into a value `:: Magic a r`. Operationally, `Magic a r` is roughly the same thing as `forall s. (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r`, so we can cross our fingers and `unsafeCoerce` it. Of course, `(Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r` is isomorphic to `a -> r`, so we just need to pass in the right function (`const a`) and `Proxy` value, and we're done.
6. The magic was in your function all along.

Comment: I'm still digesting this answer, but I don't see anything about he lack of implementations for `reflect`.

Comment: See the end of 4. We `unsafeCoerce` a function with one constraint and one argument to a function with two arguments.

Comment: That's fascinating, I didn't realize that the implementation involved using the constraint (dictionary) as an argument and coercing the function in that way. That's awesome. Great explanation.

Comment: Interestingly, the "GHC specific trick" works even on Hugs. I wouldn't recommend using it on jhc though.

Comment: There's one thing I don't understand about this implementation - but it seems fundamental, so I'm now questioning whether I really understand any of it! `Magic a r` is `unsafeCoerce`-compatible with `forall s. (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r` (because of what we know about `Reifies`'s representation), but isn't the function `k :: forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r` that was passed as an argument to `reflect` _also_ `unsafeCoerce`-compatible with that type? Why not just `unsafeCoerce k` and dispense with `Magic` altogether?

Comment: In theory, yes, but GHC's handling of type classes and polymorphic/rank-n/impredicative types can be slippery. Trying to use `unsafeCoerce k` at the type `(forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r`, GHC tries to pick some specific `s` to use. In theory you could pass the whole polymorphic function to `unsafeCoerce`, but that would be instantiating the argument at a polymorphic type, and GHC doesn't support impredicativity very well. The newtype lets you get around that.

Comment: Testing in ghci 7.10, it's possible to convince GHC to do the unsafeCoerce without the newtype with `ImpredicativeTypes`, if you're willing to be tricky: `let reify :: forall a r. a -> (forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r; reify a k = (unsafeCoerce unsafeCoerce :: (forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> (Proxy s -> a) -> Proxy s -> r) k (const a) Proxy`

Answer (score 1):

**shachaf**'s answer is not only better than mine but also correct, however I'm keeping my thoughts here for posterity.

---

This is way above me, but here is my answer anyhow.

1. `Magic` is a constructor of 2 parameters, and `unsafeCoerce` is coercing `Magic k`, which is of type `r -> Magic a r` to the type of `const a`. What it's doing here is coercing a function to be from one type to another. So the third 'argument' to `unsafeCoerce` I suspect is actually the argument being passed to the result of the `unsafeCoerce (Magic k :: Magic a r) (const a)`
2. It looks like most of the black magic is in the fact that there are no instances of `Reifies` defined, and the constructor uses an existential type. The way that existential type is actually occupied appears to occur via the `unsafeCoerce`.
3. It's defined in the coersion of the constructor to the same as being of type `const a`. This bit I understand the least.
4. The instances don't exist as far as I can tell - the existential type appears to be occupied by virtue of `unsafeCoerce` convincing the type system that, whether any instances exist or not, that a value of type `Magic a r` has been created. Whether that type exists or not, it appears to have been "forged" into existence, as in forgery, not as in metalworking.
5. The first parameter to `Magic` is the reified type as a `Proxy`, I think.
6. The magic in the newtype `Magic` is in this bit: `(forall (s :: *). Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r)` That's the type of the thing `Magic` wraps around. It specifies that the argument to `Proxy`, `s`, is an existential type of `Reifies`, or so to speak, the only fact the typesystem knows about it is that it is an instance of `Reifies`. So it knows that whatever `s` is, it must be an instance of `Reifies` and it can use that instance, but *that's all it can do*. It is like the type system has scrubbed all other knowledge of what that type is, and only knows that for the value the `Proxy` holds, it can use the function `reflect` on it - and that's it. But `reflect` recovers the value and type because the type was encoded in `Magic` and `reflect` appears to be just an `unsafeCoerce` of the function `const a`. Or at least, that's what I gather.

This may be totally wrong, but that seems to be how the pieces glue together. Or at least, how it made sense to me.